# PHP PDO Try Catch not Catching

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

I have this block of code:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $dbh->prepare('DELECT userID FROM tblusers');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

When I step through the code using the debugger in my IDE, it never enters into the `catch` block even though I have an error in my `prepare` statement.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to PDO and try/catch blocks so bear with me here if this is a dumb question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO_mysql uses emulated prepared statements by default (performance reasons), so prepare will not throw an exception. `PDOStatement::execute` will though.

You can turn emmulation off by doing as jonnyynnoj mentions, but i find catching an exception on execution is usually good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

> Emulated prepared statements does not communicate with the database server so PDO::prepare() does not check the statement.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

try / catch will only catch exceptions. Other errors (Parse errors, runtime errors, etc) won't execute the catch-block.

In your case only exceptions of type "PDOException" get caught, everything else probably gets displayed or logged (depending on your error reporting directives in php.ini).

What's being displayed as error?